# Getting operations done on Mysql by Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django and MySQL. I have a web site. 
In this web site i am using some web pages with forms that creates data and deletes data in mysql db. I want to get which DB operations are done behind when i click save button or delete button on web page. I want to see which tables are effected and which rows are created or deleted on Mysql DB.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly you want to log all queries?

Comment: https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: yes i need to log all queries